# recover all values of checked checkboxes and push them in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, twig

I am usiing twig in my php project.

I have a form which contains many checkboxes. I need, in javascript to recover all checked values of the checkbox in an array.

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
  document.getElementById("{{ value }}").onclick = function() { /* {{ value }} is value of my checkboxe, twig variable it matches like a php variable */
    if ( this.checked ) { /* check if checkboxes are checked */
      var valueChecked = this.value;
      console.log(valueChecked); /* just to display the value for debug */

      var valueArray = []; /* I create an array */
      /* here I need to put all my checkboxes values in allCheckedConfig */
    } else {
      console.log("removed " + this.value ); /* just to debug, check if checkboxes are unchecked */
    }
  };
</script>
```

How can I populate my `valueArray[]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the array like following using `map` function.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
var valueArray = Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function (obj) {
    return obj.value;
});
console.log(valueArray)
```

Comment: It seems like your answer is the good one. Indeed I need to recover all values in an array, not just only one at a time. So that what I was looking for. Thank you, I validate your answer.

Comment: My answer will recover all values, not one at a time. @french_dev

Answer (score 1):

`.push` is what you need

```
    var valueArray = [];
    document.getElementById("{{ value }}").onclick = function() { 
    if ( this.checked ) { 
      var valueChecked = this.value;
      console.log(valueChecked);
      valueArray.push(valueChecked);
      console.log(valueChecked); // Should give you the array.
    } else {
      console.log("removed " + this.value ); 
    }
  };
```

Comment: It seems like your solution works, but If I checked many checkboxes, the `valueArray[]` must return all values in array, or when I make the  `console.log()` method, the array returns me just one value at a time like `["{{value}}"]`. 
Do you think the array contains all checked value ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery on your website, you can watch [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr=$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(k,v){return $(v).val();});
```